# Simple glob command not returning anything in print statement

Tags: python, glob

I have this code to return a list of paths to files I am interested in. However, when I run this code in putty, no print statements are returned; on the command line nothing happens.

I know that the path provided should return an output, as  have used it onn the command line successfully.

Here is the code:

```
from glob import glob

#using glob package to find files for models

file_list = glob.glob('/soge-home/data/model/cmip6/CMIP6/CMIP/*/*/historical/r1i1p1f1/Amon/pr/gn/latest/*.nc', recursive=True)
file_list.sort()

#printing file names

for ifile in file_list:
    print(ifile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing glob.glob already. Don't call glob.glob(), use glob() instead

```
from glob import glob

#using glob package to find files for models

file_list = glob('/soge-home/data/model/cmip6/CMIP6/CMIP/*/*/historical/r1i1p1f1/Amon/pr/gn/latest/*.nc', recursive=True)
file_list.sort()

#printing file names

for ifile in file_list:
    print(ifile)
```

Comment: It's not clear how `recursive=True` could be meaningful here, unless each `*.nc` leaf is actually a directory. More likely the OP wants something like `/soge-home/data/model/cmip6/CMIP6/CMIP/**/historical/r1i1p1f1/Amon/pr/gn/latest/*.nc` without `recursive=True` where `**` expands to an arbitrarily nested hierarchy of directories, but really, they should clarify what they have and what they want.

Comment: Also, `glob` already sorts its results, so there really is no need to separately sort them a second time.